# How to create graph dictionary for traversal based on permutation and combination in python

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

I am facing some issues in putting things together while implementing in python (Just a beginner). I want to create set of data array on permutation and combination based on another array vector which will only be based on three types of numbers -1, 0, 1. It can be in any order and in any number. It can be `[-1 1 0 0 -1]` or `[-1 -1 0 0]` or `[-1 1]` etc.

Suppose I have data array of 4 values `[a b c d] = [5 4 0 0]` based on model chemical reaction `a + b -> c + d` then according to this reaction changing array vector be created as `v = [-1 -1 1 1]`, as **a** and **b** are producing **c** and **d** until **a** or **b** exhausted and reach `0`. Now when we apply this array vector on `[a b c d]`, we will get new array's like `[4 3 1 1], [3 2 2 2], [2 1 3 3], [1 0 4 4]`... now we cannot generate new array further as **v** cannot be applied on `[1 0 4 4]` because **b** is 0. This is a simple case. I have this simple code running to create next array but **not in loops** to create further array's :: `[3 2 0 2], [2 1 0 3], [1 0 0 4]`.

```
class SumList(object):
    def __init__(self, this_list):
        self.mylist = this_list

    def __add__(self, other):
        new_list = []
        zipped_list = zip(self.mylist, other.mylist)
        for item in zipped_list:
            new_list.append(item[0] + item[1])
        return SumList(new_list)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.mylist)

list1 = SumList([5, 4, 0, 0])
list2 = SumList([-1, -1, 1, 1])
sum = list1 + list2
print(sum)
```

**This is what I want to achieve finally::** If I have multiple reactions and multiple vector array's, like

```
a + b -> c

c -> a + b

c -> b + d

v1 = [-1 -1 1 0], 
v2 = [1 1 -1 0], 
v3 = [0 1 -1 1]
```

Where, initial quantity of `[a b c d] = [5 4 0 0]` and want to apply v1, v2 and v3 on `[a b c d]` to create new data array's, like...

**When v1 is applied on `[a b c d]` it will give**

```
[4 3 1 0], [3 2 2 0], [2 1 3 0], [1 0 4 0]
```

**When v2 is applied on `[a b c d]`** it will check that v2 cannot be applied on `[5 4 0 0]`, as number of total molecules in the system is fixed `(a=5, b=4)` at max and cannot be increased to a=6, b=5 respectively, so in this case v2 cannot give us `[6 5 -1 0]`.. so now v2 will be applied on `[4 3 1 0]` which is a 1st new array in case of v1...so we will get `[5 4 0 0]`. Now v2 will be applied on 2nd new array of v1 i.e. `[3 2 2 0]` which gives us `[4 3 1 0]`.... now v2 applied on 3rd `([2 1 3 0])` and 5th `([1 0 4 0])` new array of v1 which will give us `[3 2 2 0]` and `[2 1 3 0]` respectively. So final v2 new array list will be

```
[5 4 0 0], [4 3 1 0], [3 2 2 0], [2 1 3 0]
```

**When v3 is applied on `[a b c d]`** to it will again check if v3 can be applied on `[5 4 0 0]` or not. It clearly shows that we cannot apply v3 on `[5 4 0 0]` as it will give `[5 5 -1 -1]` which is not acceptable. So now, we need to check if we can apply v3 on new array's of v2 and v3 and have the new array list for v3.

**v3 can be applied on `[4 3 1 0]`** one time giving us new array `[4 4 0 1]`.

**v3 can be applied on `[3 2 2 0]`** two times giving us 2 new array's `[3 3 1 1]` and `[3 4 0 2]`... [Note: here b=4 so we cannot apply v3 further as b cannot exceed its initial quantity 4.... and c will be -1 which is not valid].

Once all the new array's are generated by applying v1, v2 and v3 on every possible new array, I need to take union and only print unique array's..!! As you can see some of array's are repeated in case of v1 and v2.

In simple terms, I want to apply v1, v2 and v3 on `[5 4 0 0]` and on all possible new array's, apply the checks where possible and take the union in the last and print it. I hope I have explained my problem in a simple way. Presently I trying to modify

```
from itertools import permutations
print sorted(list(set(list(permutations('5400', 4)))))
```

Any guidance on how to modify the **`Class SumList`** code is appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Comment: You can solve this with a recursive function. is this a valid solution for you?

Comment: I tried to do with recursive function as given here https://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php but i can't figure out how to write for different vectors, data array and put the check condition. In recursive function example it is given for "n", but how to write for data array and get the factorial based on vectors v1, v2...!!

Comment: how many vectors do you need to test. if the number is small, you can adapt this to a [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem

Comment: Vectors will increase if the species in the reaction is more. In the above example we have 4 species - a,b,c,d and 3 reactions, so we have 3 array vectors for 4 species v1, v2, v3. Let me check if i can do something with subset sum problem. If i get something out of this, i will post here. Many thanks.